# Slim PHP routes with special characters not working

Tags: php, rest, routes, slim

I've got the below SLIM php route:

```
$app->get('/suggest(/:filter)', 'getSuggestions');
```

It works fine when calling it as per below:

```
/suggest/query
```

But always breaks on more complicated, URI encoded queries

```
/suggest/my%20query
```

Comment: What does "break" mean? Please provide a more detailed error description, log entries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The slim forums have tons of responses around these issues - but most likely if it's not working, it's how your GET call (more likely the getSuggestions function is handling the request and any spaces it encounters. Without seeing more of that code, the best answer you will get is that your not accounting for spaces properly.